# How do i search through multiple database in grails

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, groovy

In my grails application there is a Customer domain and related customer table.
There is another database used by a java web app, which is also having customer domain and related customer table.

Also note that these two application uses two different database.

There is a customer search screen in my grails app and when the user search customer with a string i need to search for record in two database.

How can i achieve this requirement in grails ?

Can i use GORM on a database tables which is not generated by grails (i think, i can do it with hibernate mapping) ?

Answer (score 1):

We can do it by two ways:

1. Using GORM(If they have some equal columns)
2. Using Query

**Way 1:**

Create two datasource in DataSource.groovy. 
For already created database, dont give dbcreate option when define the datasource. This will prevent when ever customer object is created it will create record in Test1 databse only.
Both database having Customer table. So we can access data using GORM. For that have to define, **datasource 'ALL'** in domain.

Test1's Customer table contain name and age column
Test2's Customer Table contain name,email and phone.

By GORM, We can access only domain properties. So i can only access name from Test2's customer table.

In DataSource.groovy,

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "admin"
    password = "admin"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1"
        }
        dataSource_test2 {
            driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
            username = "admin"
                         password = "admin"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = 



   "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
                }
            }
    ..........
    .......
```

In Customer.groovy,

```
class Customer {

    static constraints = {
    }
    String name
    int age

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'ALL'
     }
}
```

In Controller,

```
class CustomerController {

    def dataSource_test2

    def testingDB(){
            Customer.test2.list().each{
                println it.name
            }
            println Customer.list()
            render "hi"

    }
}
```

Way 2:

```
class MainController {

def dataSource_test2

    def index() { 
        String nameSql = "select * from customer"
        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource_test2)
        def rows = sql.rows(nameSql)
        println rows

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

this straight foward with the following options:

1.you might need to define a new database environment on your data source groovy file just for the database source for other java web app.

```
newenvironmentname {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1"
        }
```

Then load ,or switch into the environment when you want to access the this data source at controller.

2.You need to define sql connection using groovy and

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
sql = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:
      //serverName/dbName-CLASS;domain=domainName', 'username', 'password'
      ,'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' )
sql.eachRow( 'select * from tableName' ) 
           { println "$it.id -- ${it.firstName} --" }
```

This might not be the best approach to follow...